# update recycleview row from item onclick

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycleview with 3 texts, is there a way to update specific item onclick that position, (i have quantity of each item, and i want to rise the quantity of that item onclick that position, 0,1,2,3...)
here is my receycleview:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {
    String [] Item_names,Price_items,Item_quantity;
    public RecyclerAdapter(String [] Item_names,String [] Price_items,String [] Item_quantity)
    {
        this.Item_names=Item_names;
        this.Price_items=Price_items;
        this.Item_quantity=Item_quantity;
    }
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
        RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder=new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
        return recyclerViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.ItemNameRecycler.setText(Item_names[position]);
        holder.ItemPriceRecycler.setText(Price_items[position]);
        holder.ItemQuantityRecycler.setText(Item_quantity[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return  Item_names.length;
    }
    public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView ItemPriceRecycler,ItemNameRecycler,ItemQuantityRecycler;
        public RecyclerViewHolder(View view)
        {
            super(view);
            ItemNameRecycler=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.RowItemName);
            ItemPriceRecycler=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.RowItemPrice);
            ItemQuantityRecycler=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.RowItemQuantity);
            ItemQuantityRecycler.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  [getAdapterPosition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition())

From Documentation:

> Returns the Adapter position of the item represented by this
>   ViewHolder.

in your code:

```
 public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView ItemPriceRecycler,ItemNameRecycler,ItemQuantityRecycler;
        public RecyclerViewHolder(View view)
        {
            super(view);
            ItemNameRecycler=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.RowItemName);
            ItemPriceRecycler=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.RowItemPrice);
            ItemQuantityRecycler=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.RowItemQuantity);
            ItemQuantityRecycler.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // get position
                    int pos = getAdapterPosition();  //get position here
                }
            });
        }
```

**EDIT**

for updating the `recylerview` Item `Textview` in `onClick()`

```
 public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView ItemPriceRecycler, ItemNameRecycler, ItemQuantityRecycler;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ItemNameRecycler = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.RowItemName);
            ItemPriceRecycler = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.RowItemPrice);
            ItemQuantityRecycler = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.RowItemQuantity);

            ItemQuantityRecycler.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        // onClick Listener for view
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (v.getId() == ItemQuantityRecycler.getId()) {
                int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                int value = pos + 1;
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "ITEM PRESSED = " + String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ItemQuantityRecycler.setText(String.valueOf(value));
            } else {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: but how can i change the value of that pos, how do i update this specific position?

Comment: what do u mean? update this postion `TextView` like `ItemQuantityRecycler`..?

Comment: yeah, you see, i have 3 columns, one for the item name, one for his price, and one for his quantity, lets say i have about 30 items, i want to rise the number of the quantity by 1 when the user presses the item name.

Comment: actually i want to know about the word `rise`...add a count variable and add 1 to it each time user press ??

Comment: English is not my native language so sorry for the bad English.
anyway, yeah thats what i want but how can i  change the quantity only to this position

Comment: It wasn't exactly what i wanted, but what i wanted is working now. thank you!